How to add a page break in mermaid Sequence Diagram?
I have a long seq diagram created in mermaid that span across 2 pages.
Unfortunately, the page break doesn't break at the right place when print to PDF from the browser.
How to I create page break to prevent the seq diag from page breaking at the wrong place in PDF printout?

If I knew the place where the page break shall occur, I would split the sequence diagram into two so that each is printed on one page. This would have the additional advantage that the labels above the actors are repeated on the second page, enhancing readability.
